# Python Turtle window not working

Tags: python

I'm using atom as an editor for my code and using python3 on mac. It's not giving me any error messages. I tried downloading a turtle package as a plugin but didn't work. Please help.

```
import turtle
def polygon(t, n, length):
    angle= 360/n

    for i in range (n):
        t.forward(length)
        t.left(angle)
        t=turtle.Turtle()

    polygon(t, 6, 100)
```

Comment: You should edit your question so the indentation is correct and matches the code you are trying to run. You should also describe how you're attempting to invoke this code and what happens when you do. See [ask]

Comment: where you have defined `t` by the way ?

Comment: @bhansa im really still new at this, so i dont know much about coding,

Comment: you should post your errors as well.

Comment: If you want to try and run the function, while showing any error messages in your terminal when executing the Python script, put the code inside your polygon function in a try/except block, printing the error if there is an exception, https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions. Also you need to instantiate a turtle object ***"t = turtle.Turtle()"*** before assigning values to t.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the code is just indented incorrectly. It has the turtle creation in the for loop. I reformatted it and added some space for clarity below.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some different indentation. Try this:

```
import turtle

def polygon(t, n, length):
    angle= 360/n

    for i in range (n):
        t.forward(length)
        t.left(angle)

t=turtle.Turtle()

polygon(t, 6, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

There was another file in the same directory called turtle.py, giving me the error when importing turtle. As well as, i had a problem in the indentation,

```
import turtle
def polygon(t, n, length):
    angle= 360/n

    for i in range (n):
       t.forward(length)
       t.left(angle)
t=turtle.Turtle()
polygon(t, 6, 100)
```

this is the right code, thank you all:)